# Can I partition the array in K sizes?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, partitioning, greedy

I am trying to implement the algorithm from this question: [Need idea for solving this algorithm puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592143/need-idea-for-solving-this-algorithm-puzzle), but i am missing some edge case which is causing my code to go in infinite loop. I can fix it by doing some cosmetic change but it shows that i didn't understand the algorithm.

Can someone help me out, what i am missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b));
int get_max(int *a, int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size)
        return 0;
    return max(a[i], get_max(a, i+1, size));
}

int get_sum(int *a, int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size)
        return 0;
    return a[i] + get_sum(a, i+1, size);
}

int get_partition(int *a, int size, int bound) {
    int running_sum = 0;
    int partitions = 0, i;

    for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if (a[i] + running_sum <= bound) {
            running_sum += a[i];
        } else {
            running_sum = 0;
            running_sum += a[i];
            partitions++;
        }
    }
    return partitions;
}

int foo(int *a, int size, int k)
{
    int lower = get_max(a, 0, size);
    int higher = get_sum(a, 0, size);
    int partition;

    while (lower < higher) {
        int bound = (lower + (higher))/2;

        partition = get_partition(a, size, bound);
        printf("partition %d bound %d lower %d higher %d\n", partition, bound, lower, higher);
        if (partition >= k) 
            lower = bound;
        else
            higher = bound;
    }
    return partition;
}

#define SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
int main(void) {
    int a[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    printf("%d\n", foo(a, SIZE(a), 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
partition 1 bound 13 lower 6 higher 20
partition 2 bound 9 lower 6 higher 13
partition 3 bound 7 lower 6 higher 9
partition 3 bound 8 lower 7 higher 9
partition 3 bound 8 lower 8 higher 9
...last line keeps repeating.
```

Comment: Please include the first two repeated lines of output and one to three preceding it. Guessing: lower == bound == higher-1 < partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of mistakes:

- during the binary search, your while test should be `while (lower+1 < higher) {` and not `while (lower < higher) {`. You are entering infinite loop when `lower = 8`, `higher = 9`. At this stage, your `bound` would be `(lower+higher)/2=8`and you would update `lower = bound` which would not change anything.
- at the end of `foo` you should return `higher` (not partitions) since your binary search invariant is that for having `bound <= lower` you can partition the array in more than `k` parts and for`bound >= higher`  you can partition it in `k` or less.
- your calculation of `get_partition` is wrong. You don't take into the account the last partition group since you only update `partitions` when you overflow `running_sum`. After the for-cycle you should have the statement :

  ```
  if (running_sum > 0) 
      partitions++;
  ```

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b));
int get_max(int *a, int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size)
        return 0;
    return max(a[i], get_max(a, i+1, size));
}

int get_sum(int *a, int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size)
        return 0;
    return a[i] + get_sum(a, i+1, size);
}

int get_partition(int *a, int size, int bound) {
    int running_sum = 0;
    int partitions = 0, i;

    for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if (a[i] + running_sum <= bound) {
            running_sum += a[i];
        } else {
            running_sum = 0;
            running_sum += a[i];
            partitions++;
        }
    }
    if (running_sum > 0)
        partitions++;
    return partitions;
}

int foo(int *a, int size, int k)
{
    int lower = get_max(a, 0, size);
    int higher = get_sum(a, 0, size);
    int partition;

    while (lower+1 < higher) {
        int bound = (lower + (higher))/2;

        partition = get_partition(a, size, bound);
        printf("partition %d bound %d lower %d higher %d\n", partition, bound, lower, higher);
        if (partition > k)
            lower = bound;
        else
            higher = bound;
    }
    printf("partition %dlower %d higher %d\n", partition, lower, higher);
    return higher;
}

#define SIZE(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
int main(void) {
    int a[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    printf("%d\n", foo(a, SIZE(a), 3));
    return 0;
}
```